# Alter node menu local task weight of "View" and "Edit" for a content type

Tags: navigation

I want to alter the ordering of the node tabs for a particular content type.

- *From this*: View, Edit
- *To this*: Edit, View

I tried with using menu_local_tasks_alter like this:

```
function wedding_registry_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
      foreach ($router_item['page_arguments'] as $key => $argument) {
        if (is_object($argument) && $router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type == 'my_wedding_registry') {
            dpm($data);
            foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $link) {
                if ($link['#link']['path'] == 'node/%/view') {
                    dpm($link['#link']['weight']);
                    $data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['weight'] = 5;
                    dpm($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['weight']);
                }
                elseif ($link['#link']['path'] == 'node/%/edit') {
                    dpm($link['#link']['weight']);
                    $data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['weight'] = 4;
                    dpm($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['weight']);
                }
            }
            dpm($data);
        }
      }
    }
```

Devel is showing the $data array correctly modified:

- first with the default weights (View = -100, Edit = -99)
- after with my modified weigths (View = 5, Edit = 4)

but the tabs on the page are **still on the same positions** even after clearing the cache!